# Using media.js on CI

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, media, pdfviewer

I was still newbie at CI, currently try to make elearning just using one page,
using 2 div on the main body, left and right.

on the left I give just the title and when clicking on the title, the div on the right will show the pdf viewer using media.js from http://github.com/malsup/media/tree/master

But when I tried, the result just show on the next page in full page.

any body could help me or suggest to the right links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple PDF viewer for php websites check it out :
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: I try use Flexpaper, but it was just open .swf file,
   { config : {

                SWFFile : 'docs/Paper.pdf.swf',

             ----
i change to PDFFile and the page didn't show the pdf file I choose